# ABAddressBookSave crashes when adding a kABPersonAddressProperty

Tags: ios, objective-c, abaddressbook

I am making an app where I need to save a contact to the address book. Everything works fine except when I add the `kABPersonAddressProperty`, first I add them then i save the address and it crashes while saving.

The error I am getting is:

```
-[__NSCFString count]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x99e6f30
*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[__NSCFString count]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x99e6f30'
```

Here is the code that I am using:

```
ABRecordRef aRecord = ABPersonCreate();
CFErrorRef  anError = NULL;
//
//some code here, not relevant
//
ABMutableMultiValueRef multiAdd = ABMultiValueCreateMutable(kABMultiStringPropertyType);
ABMultiValueAddValueAndLabel(multiAdd, (__bridge CFStringRef)self.Street.text, kABPersonAddressStreetKey, NULL);
ABMultiValueAddValueAndLabel(multiAdd, (__bridge CFStringRef)self.ZIPcode.text, kABPersonAddressZIPKey, NULL);
ABMultiValueAddValueAndLabel(multiAdd, (__bridge CFStringRef)self.City.text, kABPersonAddressCityKey, NULL);

ABRecordSetValue(aRecord, kABPersonAddressProperty, multiAdd, &anError);
CFRelease(multiAdd);

//More irrelevant code here


ABAddressBookRef addressBook;
CFErrorRef error = NULL;
addressBook = ABAddressBookCreateWithOptions(nil, NULL);

BOOL isAdded = ABAddressBookAddRecord (addressBook, aRecord, &error);

if(isAdded){
    NSLog(@"added..");
}
if (error != NULL) {
    NSLog(@"ABAddressBookAddRecord %@", error);
}

error = NULL;

BOOL isSaved = ABAddressBookSave (addressBook, &error);
```

Whenever I run this code, the error are always NULL, and isAdded is always true, but still it crashes while executing `ABAddressBookSave(addressBook,&error);`
Another important thing is that if I delete this part of code:

```
ABMutableMultiValueRef multiAdd = ABMultiValueCreateMutable(kABMultiStringPropertyType);
ABMultiValueAddValueAndLabel(multiAdd, (__bridge CFStringRef)self.Street.text, kABPersonAddressStreetKey, NULL);
ABMultiValueAddValueAndLabel(multiAdd, (__bridge CFStringRef)self.ZIPcode.text, kABPersonAddressZIPKey, NULL);
ABMultiValueAddValueAndLabel(multiAdd, (__bridge CFStringRef)self.City.text, kABPersonAddressCityKey, NULL);

ABRecordSetValue(aRecord, kABPersonAddressProperty, multiAdd, &anError);
CFRelease(multiAdd);
```

The contact is added fine, with name, last name, multiple phone numbers, URL and email.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The address property is not a `kABMultiStringPropertyType`, but instead a `kABMultiDictionaryPropertyType`.

To resolve the crash try changing your call to `ABMultiValueCreateMutable` by passing it the right type, `kABMultiDictionaryPropertyType`.

And then you'll also need to update how you are populating the address information by creating a dictionary out of the address string values. Check out [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3458590/addressbook-trying-to-add-home-and-work-addresses-only-1-shows-up) for an example on that.

It should look something like this (untested):

```
ABMultiValueRef addresses = ABMultiValueCreateMutable(kABMultiDictionaryPropertyType);
   NSDictionary *values = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                               self.Street.text, (NSString *)kABPersonAddressStreetKey,
                               self.ZIPcode.text, (NSString *)kABPersonAddressZIPKey,
                               self.City.text, (NSString *)kABPersonAddressCityKey,
                               nil];

ABMultiValueAddValueAndLabel(addresses, (CFDictionaryRef)values, kABHomeLabel, NULL);
ABRecordSetValue(aRecord, kABPersonAddressProperty, addresses, &anError);
```

Comment: Ok, this totally makes sense, I am gonna give it a try. Cheers.